# LINQ join, group and sum (or any aggregate)

Tags: c#, linq, group-by, aggregate

Have order header and details tables, want to grab all the header columns and append a summed order quantity from the details.

What I'm trying to do (pseudo-sql):

```
select Header.*, sum(Details.Quantity)
from Header
join Details on Details.HeaderID = Header.ID
group by HeaderID
```

To avoid re-writing all the Header columns (there are alot) I've created a new object like so:

```
public class OrderView 
{
    public Header Header { get; set; }
    public int? TotalQuantity { get; set; }
}
```

And my sad attempt to fill it:

```
var results = from oh in db.Header
              join od in db.Details on oh.ID equals od.HeaderID                          
              where oh.Store == params.Store
                 // && ...  a bunch more search filters on Header ...
              group od by od.PID into odg
              select new OrderView() { Header = oh, TotalQuantity = odg.Sum(x => x.QTY) };
```

The first problem with my current attempt is that in the `select` line, `oh` is not defined, which in my ignorance of LINQ leads me to believe all the results from the Header have been sent somewhere else.

I'm perfectly okay scrapping this entire query and doing it differently if there is a best practice for this type of querying that I'm not seeing in my searches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean something like this? I *am* assuming `od.PID` is really `od.HeaderID` (= `oh.ID`) from your pesudo-sql in your "what I'm trying to do", *and* that `oh.ID` is unique (possible PK?) for each row in `db.Header` and therefore you can group by the row itself.

```
var results = from oh in db.Header
              join od in db.Details on oh.ID equals od.HeaderID                          
              where oh.Store == params.Store
                 // && ...  a bunch more search filters on Header ...
              group od by oh into odg
              select new OrderView() 
              {
                  Header = odg.Key, 
                  TotalQuantity = odg.Sum(x => x.QTY) 
              };
```

Comment: Yes, yes I did.  So `.Key` is a built-in property for what you group by.  Good to know.

Comment: Yes it is, you get an [IGrouping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb344977.aspx) out of a group by.